# Store a .p12 file and implement SSL in an iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a demo in which I am implementing SSL Pining.

In that, I have **added .p12 certificate in the main bundle** and then after I was using it, but the .p12 certificate is actually **extractable from .ipa file.**

**What is the best approach to use the certificate and where should I store it in the application?**

I thought of retrieving the data from Firebase, but again If I use **Firebase** Database, it is having **public storage**, and the firebase **configuration file is also extractable from ipa file** which can then cause a security issue.

*I have taken care of the coding for SSL pining coding from the application side. I need guidance for fetching / storing certificate in my application.*

What should I do in such a case?

Comment: if the `.p12` file is sensitive, you could always split into different size of chucks, convert it to arrays of `[Int8]` and obfuscate it in the source then put together in runtime then push into keychain directly – but in general, no, you need to have the content somewhere in the project where you can load it from and push into keychain after all.

Comment: OKay,Can you please help me to understand how you suggest to download the certificate at firsttime in application ?

Comment: I did not suggest to download it at all... you said the certificate is in the bundle at the first place, so you can keep it as a file in the bundle, or you can take further steps to split into smaller binary chunks of array of bites and obfuscate it by embedding into the source code – then build the certificate in runtime then to store into keychain, if that is necessary; but in general __it is a bad idea__ to store anything into your bundle which is not a public-key or publicly available information for SSL pinning (e.g. the certificate itself).

Comment: @holex : Thanks, I understand. One more thing I need to place this on the cloud, can you suggest the cloud which is counted as secure. I already check firebase, but wothout authentication it is not secure.

Comment: well... if you actually want to store or even transfer private certificates through the web, that sounds like a __really bad idea__ – it is much safer to embed such information into your bundle (still a bad idea), since you can rely on the secure connection between you users and AppStore in general – and keep your private information in a physical safe (however, I don't know how sensitive the data you want to protect by SSL Pinning), never upload private keys to anywhere, I strongly recommend to use public keys only or the publicly available certificate itself and embed those into the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the iOS **Keychain** in order to store the cert.

There is an excellent overview here from [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH224-SW1) official docs.

Whenever you are comfortable with that, check out this implementation [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/storing_a_certificate_in_the_keychain) from Apple.

Comment: okay, Now I have one certificate (Physical file) which I need to append with every api call, should I keep that in bundle and then keychain ? or is there any other way to get that certificate and store it in keychain without placing physical file ?